# Split Excel spreadsheet by variable number of rows (eg: about 5,000 rows plus max 1,000)

Tags: vba, excel, split

**How to split an excel file into several files not knowing in advance the exact number of rows where to tell Excel to split, but knowing only a rough number where to split ?**

*Example:* 100,000 rows in total. In Column A, I have many rows which starts by the same cell content. I know that I have a maximum of 1,000 rows that have the same Column A content.

*row# : Column A content* :

row1:namedBB

row2:namedBB

...

row251:namedBB

row252:namedCC

...

row4,999:namedDD

row5,000:namedDD

...

row5,365:namedDD

row5,366:namedKEI

...etc...

In this example, I would like to split the file to about each 5,000 rows.
But in fact the first split should be exactly on 5,366 (so the first xslx file will have content from row1 to row5,365, and the second xslx file will have from row5,366 to ?...).

Here is the VBA code that I use to split with a fixed number of rows.

```
Sub Splitter_fixed_number_of_rows()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lTop As Long, lBottom, lCopy As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim wbNew As Workbook, sPath As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("recap")  ' sheetname to adapt
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lTop = 2
Do

lBottom = lTop + 5000   ' fixed number of row where to split //to adapt
If lBottom > LastRow Then lBottom = LastRow
lCopy = lCopy + 1

Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).Copy
wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
.Range(.Cells(lTop, 1), .Cells(lBottom, LastCol)).Copy
wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial

wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="TEST_" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & lCopy, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook ' split into .xslx files
wbNew.Close

lTop = lBottom + 1
Loop While lTop <= LastRow
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Can you define how "roughly 5000" and "about 5000" rows are calculated ? A computer cannot do "roughly" something. You need to come up with a precise idea how to separate your data before we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your question. It can be minimum 5000 rows and maximum 6000 rows. The way to find exactly where to separate the file is to find where the columnA content is changing after 5000 (but before 6000). In the example the content of the cells A5000 to A5365 is the same. And starting from the cell A5366, the content changes. Please let me know if it is not more understandable. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: From what I am reading, the content is not split by a specified amount of rows, but by the content in each row?

Comment: Dave, I can have different contents in columnA before row 5,000. I would like that the files have at least 5,000 rows but not more than 6,000. Thanks ;)

Comment: Is it 5000 rows of content OR 5000 rows regardless their bearing content or not in them?

Comment: @Aman, I am sorry I don't think I understand your question well ! Here is maybe an idea to help : I can add a column and add formulas like B2=if(A2=A3,"same_content","different_content")... Like that it might be easier to find exactly where to cut the file between 5,000 and 6,000. Then between 10,365 (5365+5000) and 11,365 (5365+6,000)...etc... Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: How about saving the value of col A in `lBottom = lTop + 5000` and  then check when the next different value comes up? Multiple options, e.g. `while` or `GoTo`, search `vba find next cell with different content` or sth equivalent for solutions. As soon as a different value comes up, split. I know, it's kind of brute-force, but it does the trick.

Comment: Klaster, Thanks. ;) It could be the correct way to go, alas I am not good enough with vba to do it (I have just found the above code somewhere and tried to easily adapt it to my needs). Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Thanks to all who helped. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add the below line of code to dynamically search for the 5xxxth row

Append the following few lines below `lCopy = lCopy + 1`

```
For lBottom = lBottom To lBottom + 999
    If Range("A" & lBottom) <> Range("A" & lBottom + 1) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next lBottom
```

New Modified Code

```
Sub Splitter_fixed_number_of_rows()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lTop As Long, lBottom, lCopy As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim wbNew As Workbook, sPath As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("recap")  ' sheetname to adapt
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lTop = 2
Do

lBottom = lTop + 5000   ' fixed number of row where to split //to adapt
lCopy = lCopy + 1

For lBottom = lBottom To lBottom + 999
    If Range("A" & lBottom) <> Range("A" & lBottom + 1) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next lBottom

If lBottom > LastRow Then lBottom = LastRow

Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).Copy
wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
.Range(.Cells(lTop, 1), .Cells(lBottom, LastCol)).Copy
wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial

wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="TEST_" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & lCopy, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook ' split into .xslx files
wbNew.Close

lTop = lBottom + 1
Loop While lTop <= LastRow
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks. ;) After tests, it is very close, but it is not split exactly where it should be. Example: In the first split, the last row is in fact belonging to the top of the second split file. This is repeated for the next splits. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I have updated the code to account for that do try now error was in the old lbotttom + 1 it should instead have bee only lbotttom do rerun the above code I have edited

Comment: wow ! Many thanks. ;) In my tests so far it worked like a charm. Thank you again. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
rcount = 0
nameseries = ""

For i = lTop + 1 To LastRow
cellname = Cells(i, 1)
If rcount > 5000 Then
    If cellname <> nameseries Then
        rcount = 0
        nameseries = cellname
        'generate new file, range that needs be copied is header and Range(Cells(i-rcount,LastColumn),Cells(i,LastColumn)
    End If
rcount = rcount + 1
End If

End Sub
```

I would simply split the dataset to worksheets, 100,000 isn't that much.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly:

```
Sub M_snb()
  On Error Resume Next

  Do
    With Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub

      .Cells(1).Resize(Application.Match(.Cells(1).Value, .Offset(0), 1)).Cut
      Sheets.Add.Paste
    End With
  Loop
End Sub
```